# Using UILongPressGestureRecognizer For Subviews of UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

For the past four hours, I have tried many Stack Overlow solutions but none have helped solve my problem.

Here it is,

- I have a **UIScrollView**
- Within that ScrollView there is **one custom UILabel and 8 custom UIImageViews**
- I want to detect a **long press**
- Something like this works

  `UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDidFire:)];

  longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5; 
  [scroll addGestureRecognizer:longPress]; //scroll defined elsewhere`

However, if I replace the scroll with any subviews of scroll, the long press event never fires.

> 1. How do I detect a long press of a subview of a scroll view?
> 2. This is quite a messy hack, however, since I can detect long presses of a scroll view, is there any way where I can detect the
>      position of the press so that I can see which specific subview is
>      being pressed.

Also, `(insert subview here).userInteractionEnabled = YES`, I set this property for all my subviews of the scroll view, so this should not be a problem.

I have also tried using touchesBegan and touchesEnded method as suggested elsewhere in Stack Overflow.

Also, for the image views, I do set a new UILongPressGestureRecognizer for every custom image view, using a for loop, as I am **aware of the 1 view per gesture recognizer** rule.

From A First Time iOS Developer,

Graham

P.S. I'd really prefer if I could find a solution for 1. rather than the messy 2.

---

More Code As Requested:

In the Init of the view Controller

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDidFire:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
[self.titleLabel addGestureRecognizer:longPress]; //titleLabel property initialized elsewhere
[mainView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
```

In a "load images" method

```
for (NSData * dataImg in results) {
//Does some work turning data into an image, into an image view called img
        img.delegate = self;
        img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *aLongPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDidFire:)];
        aLongPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
        [img addGestureRecognizer:aLongPress];
        [imgContainer addSubview:img];
}
```

---

Even More Code + Notes

> self.view (UIView)
>
> ->scroll (UIScrollView)
>
> ->->mainView (UIView)
>
> ->->->titleLabel (UILabel)
>
> ->->->imgContainer (UIView)
>
> ->->->->images (UIImageViews)

```
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[scroll addSubview:mainView];
[mainView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
[mainView addSubview:imgContainer];
[imgContainer addSubview:img]; //done 8x via for loop
```

Thanks to @RegularExpression's answer, I now am aware that the mainView is getting pressed, but not its subviews, so I need to find a way to display the mainView's subviews above it. :)

Another update, titleLabel works. ImageViews still don't work though. :(

Comment: How're you adding `subViews` to `UIScrollView` ?

Comment: Loading code, give me a sec. Thanks for the help. @TheTiger

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you earlier, have now posted how I add views to my scrollview @TheTiger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woohoo it works!

The problem was:

imgContainer was a **UIView with an empty frame** with several UIImageViews as subviews

I was *under the impression that as I added a subview to imgContainer, imgContainer would expand*.

This is *not true*.

I had to **set imgContainer's frame to the same content frame as the scroll view** and then everything became ok.

I hope this answer helps any other future iOS firs timers like me.

Comment: Something like you're playing alone :/ First of all we dont have your code we just answered about what you asked. Now have a look at your question can any one give the answer like you have given here ? I think **NO** because you know what you wrote .... any way happy coding.

Comment: I did not mean to be unclear. All of you did well, with what was given to you (although you basically had the same code as I did). Nevertheless, I feel the need to give out the final, real answer in case anybody suffers from this problem in the future. @TheTiger

Answer (score 12):

I know this is a bit late and an answer has been chosen, but in case someone else wants a nice simple solution if you've got iOS7.

Inside your delegate of the **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** implement the **gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer** selector

Check if **otherGestureRecognizer** is a **UIPanGestureRecognizer** and return YES, otherwise return NO

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

The scroll view will actually produce a UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer, which is part of the private API, but it's a subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer so the above works fine.

To support iOS6 or below, then you'll need to loop through the gestureRecognizers of the UIScrollView, detect which one is a **UIPanGestureRecognizer** and perform the **requireGestureRecognizerToFail** selector on your **UILongPressGestureRecogizer** with that.

Answer (score 2):

your code seems to be fine,it should work i think.i used below code and its working fine for me.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.delegate = (id)self;
longPress.minimumPressDuration=0.05;
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

and its method,

```
- (IBAction)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
   NSLog(@"detected");

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"YES"    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
     [alert show];
   } 
}
```

Here i took imageView as subview of scrollview as u said

Comment: Thanks, I posted my code above, it is very similar to yours, apart from (id)self. But it does not work, unfortunately. @murali

Comment: sorry I misunderstood you earlier, have now posted how I add views to my scrollview @murali

Comment: Scrollview is in xib or programmatically you are adding ?? @GangstaGraham

Answer (score 1):

Since your UIScrollView is the common parent, that's probably where your gesture recognizer needs to be.  You can determine which subview is being pressed by looking at the location of the point supplied in your action.  So, the individual subviews do not need gesture recognizers.

So, you would do something like this:

```
- (void)longPressDidFire:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:scroll];
        UIView *tappedView = [scroll hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
```

So, then you have the view that was long-pressed.

Other things that could cause the action not to fire would be a delegate problem or if the scroll is contained by another view that is intercepting the touch.

HTH

Comment: This seems interesting, @RegularExpression , I will check it out

Comment: But how would you find the specific UIView, all it gives is Memory Allocations, since there are 8 custom UIImageViews, I don't know if this will work.

Comment: Thanks though, this helped me figure out that the mainView is getting tapped, but not the mainView's subviews. That was helpful!

Comment: See my answer above and upvote if you like it. :) @RegularExpression

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 [scroll addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Add the gesture on your subviews, right after you declare them and before you add them to scrollview

```
 [subview addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Comment: ^Forgot to tag you above  @mayuur

Comment: Ok, could you post how are you adding views inside your scrollview?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood you earlier, have now posted how I add views to my scrollview @mayuur