# Swift: Conflict between LongPressGestureRecognizer and scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have a UIView within a UIScrollView. I want the view to do something when a tap on it begins, and do something different when the tap ends. Therefor I used a UILongPressGestureRecognizer. I set the minimumPressDuration to zero. This works fine, but my problem is that I can't use the scroll view properly anymore because every touch within the view now fires the gesture recognizer.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?
Can I tell the LongPressGestureRecognizer not to react on swipe gestures?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870756/using-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-for-subviews-of-uiscrollview

Comment: use [viewObject addGestureRecognizer:longPress]; Or longPress.minimumPressDuration=0.05;

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting:

```
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Also try using a `UILongPressGestureRecogniser` with:

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Where `ViewController` is the `delegate` of your gesture recogniser.